# how to check offset for a program on remote server

Tags: exploit-development, ctf

I am solving pwn problems in CTF challenges. my exploits are working in the local system but it doesn't work on the remote server when connecting using Netcat. The issue was that even the function address is the same offset was different in the local and remote server. How can I find out the offset used on the remote server?

Comment: In short: you can't.

Comment: It depends why there is a different address (PIE, ASLR, etc.) and what type of exploit you are writing. Maybe the question could be answered with those details. Or maybe there is an information leak somewhere, or brute force is possible due to it being a forking daemon.